# Mysql; CASE; multiple WHEN ? THEN ?. How to create data for ? with foreach

Tags: php, mysql, case

Have input rows with following values (as example, show only 2 rows, but there may much more rows; of course values may be different)

```
       entry_id | transaction_partner_name | registration_number
values
          10             name 1                   number 1
          11             name 2                   number 2
```

Must update mysql table with the values

Query may be like this

```
 UPDATE 2_1_transactionpartners SET 
 CompanyName = CASE NumberRenamed 
 WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? 
 END, 
 RegistrationNumber = CASE NumberRenamed 
 WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? 
 END 
 WHERE NumberRenamed in (?,?)
```

or

```
$sql = "
    UPDATE 2_1_transactionpartners SET
    CompanyName = CASE NumberRenamed
    $when_then
    END, 
    RegistrationNumber = CASE NumberRenamed
    $when_then
    END
    WHERE NumberRenamed in ($placeholders_for_number_renamed)";
```

Now within foreach create variables

```
$entry_id_for_number_renamed = array();

foreach ($_POST['entry_id'] as $i => $entry_id) {

    $for_company_name .= ( $_POST['entry_id'][$i]. ','. $_POST['transaction_partner_name'][$i]. ',' );

    $for_registration_number .= ( $_POST['entry_id'][$i]. ','. $_POST['registration_number'][$i]. ',' );

    $entry_id_for_number_renamed[] = $_POST['entry_id'][$i];

    $when_then .= 'WHEN ? THEN ? ';
    $placeholders_for_number_renamed .= '?,';

}

$for_company_name = rtrim($for_company_name, ',');
$for_company_name = explode(',', $for_company_name);

$for_registration_number = rtrim($for_registration_number, ',');
$for_registration_number = explode(',', $for_registration_number);

$insertData = array_merge( $for_company_name, $for_registration_number, $entry_id_for_number_renamed );
```

If idea about better (shorter) solution, please advice

Comment: pleas tell us at first what you are going to achieve with the code. so what is the goal, the desired output, etc. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE transactionpartners
SET transaction_partner_name = q.transaction_partner_name,
    registration_number      = q.registration_number
FROM (
    SELECT 10          AS entry_id                ,
        'new name 1'   AS transaction_partner_name,
        'new number 2' AS registration_number

    UNION

    SELECT 11          AS entry_id                ,
        'new name 3'   AS transaction_partner_name,
        'new number 4' AS registration_number
    )
    q
WHERE q.entry_id = transactionpartners.entry_id
```

Comment: Excuse me, possibly misunderstanding. Want to update with input values (user enters values in html input). And question/problem is that my code is rather long (for example, if need to update many input columns) In question only 2 columns (`CompanyName ` and `RegistrationNumber`). Actually there are 9 columns. So need to repeat code for all 9 columns. If latter add some column, then must update code (may forget to update). May be exists some shorter and simpler solution.

Comment: Does not matter how many columns/rows you have. All columns defined as virtual fields(`<field> AS col_name`) and rows(blocks separated by UNION). Alternatives: you can create temp table/view and update from it, but it is a 3 operations(create temp table, fill temp table, update from temp table). Simply nowhere.